# Installing an email signature using MSI package

Tags: email, outlook, windows-installer, signature

I'm working with a client who's employees don't know how to use outlook for reasons other than sending and receiving emails. I want to know, is there a a way to create and MSI package that will not only install the email signatures into each users pc but also change things like font and font color?

I've tried using `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Signatures` as the install location, but it just  ended up installing the signatures to the Documents folder.

Answer (score 0):

Placing signature files to the Signatures folder is not enough... There are several possible approaches to setting the signature:

1. Set the NewSignature and ReplySignature string values in the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\MailSettings key to the name of the signature. Where the 14.0 stands for the Outlook version. For example, 15.0 - Outlook 2013; 14.0 - Outlook 2010. Be aware, this may not take effect until the user opens the Signatures dialog in Outlook.
2. Use a [script](http://www.outlookcode.com/codedetail.aspx?id=821) to apply the signature to each account by hacking the Profiles section of the registry.
3. Use Word's EmailOptions.EmailSignature object, see [Setting Up Outlook E-Mail Signatures](https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/2006.10.heyscriptingguy(en-us).aspx) for more information. Note, you need to open your signature (HTML) file in Word in order to use it to set the signature.